# how do i get rid of a key error in jupyter notebook?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, data-science

otherwise when i remove the inplace=true, it works just fine
here is the code:
in: x=df1.drop('Outcome', axis=1, inplace=True)
y=df1['Outcome']

out: KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
3360             try:
-> 3361                 return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
3362             except KeyError as err:

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

pandas_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

KeyError: 'Outcome'

Answer (score 0):

Have you understood what `inplace=True` does ?

```
x=df1.drop('Outcome', axis=1, inplace=True)
```

creates an empty object x (because `df1.drop('Outcome', axis=1, inplace=True)` works by side effect so returns nothing) AND will drop the `Outcome` column of the df1 dataframe.
Thus, `y=df1['Outcome']` will create an error as this column no longer exists.

On the other hand,

```
x=df1.drop('Outcome', axis=1)
```

will create a new dataframe x which is df1 without the `Outcome` column. So df1 still contains this column, and you have no error when executing your second line